# VueJS port not accessible or crashing with GitHub Codespaces

Tags: vue.js, codespaces, github-codespaces

In a blank repository, I've set up a new Codespace that I've opened in VSCode for the Desktop on Windows 11. Within that I've ran the following:

```
npm create vue@latest .
✔ Project name: ...
✔ Add TypeScript? … No / [Yes]
✔ Add JSX Support? … [No] / Yes
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … [No] / Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … [No] / Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit testing? … No / [Yes]
✔ Add an End-to-End Testing Solution? … [No] / Cypress / Playwright
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? … No / [Yes]
✔ Add Prettier for code formatting? … No / [Yes]
```

And then ran the standard:

```
npm install
npm run format
npm run dev
```

It then successfully says that the project is accessible on port 5173, but if I attempt to open localhost:5173 in the browser nothing happens, it doesn't seem to be connected to the port within the Codespace despite the ports list showing it as Auto Forwarded

Further to this, attempting to set the port from private to public crashes the Codespace entirely. However, if I instead run `npm run dev` within VSCode for Web, it all works out fine - any ideas? I'd rather not use the web version because my muscle memory is hardwired to hit Ctrl + W to close the tab within VSCode which closes the Codespace entirely

Comment: When you run applications within a Codespace, they're actually running in a remote environment, not on your local machine. Therefore, accessing localhost directly won't work as you might expect. When you run an application in a Codespace, GitHub should provide a forwarded URL that you can use to access the application. This URL will not be localhost, but rather a unique URL generated by GitHub. Check the terminal or the Ports view in VSCode for a link to open the app.

Comment: VSCode does not list any non-localhost URL in either the terminal or the ports window until you change it from Private to Public, which crashes the Codespace for me only if I try it with this VueJS instance, anything else works fine. If I run anything else (e.g. `npx http-server`) that is working as expected as localhost:8080 is forwarded to whatever URL the actual remote server is using under the hood and I can also make it Public to get a non localhost URL. This only seems to be an issue with the port exposed by VueJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this, I added the `--host` flag to my package.json:

```
"dev": "vite --host",
```

which solved the issue